# How can I add collapsible Details on row column?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to build a system which makes an .row.col expansible on the full width with custom information. This should look somehow like this:[image]

As a test for this, I created a row with some entries. To simulate the boxes, I've created custom divs with fixed heights and widths but now I am running into the following problem: The div including the information overflows the next columns. Instead of this, the next cols should start below the green information div.

[image]

You can find my codepen.io here: https://codepen.io/PascalKu/pen/zYLjZoO

```css
.row {
  position: relative;
}

.col {
  height: fit-content;
}

.element {
  display: block;
  background: orange;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.element-details {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element-details"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Absolute position won't work because that element is outside the document flow. Why not just put it in its own row?

Comment: @isherwood then all other col elements will jump into the next row below the details opener.

Comment: True. You haven't made it clear what behavior you want. What's a "row" here? With no column size designation it's variable.